# print COUNT SQL

Tags: php, sql

I have a column num_id, which is an int primary key. I need to print out how many records there is in that column.

I have tried to make something, but it is not quite working. The database connection is fine, and the SQL query should also be fine. But how do I print it out?

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include 'dbconfic.inc.php';

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT (*) AS num_id FROM numbertable")) {

    /* determine number of rows result set */
    $row_cnt = $stmt->num_rows;

    printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);

    /* close result set */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php).

Comment: what you commented out should work; what's the real question? minus the `$res = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {` mixing APIs that is and `mysql_fetch_assoc`. hold on here; that won't work.

Comment: *"The database connection is fine"* - being what exactly?? mysql_? mysqli_? PDO?

Comment: plus, you've nothing "to" prepare. Sorry, but your question's way too unclear for my taste; I'll pass on this one.

Comment: I have a column, and I want to print how many record there is in this column. I cannot see that is unclear??

Comment: You're mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions. That won't work.

Comment: "I have a column, and I want to print how many record there is in this column." :-) You have a *table* consisting of columns and rows. You don't have records in a *column*. You have records (rows) in a *table*. You have values in a column. You can count how many records you get, regardless which columns you select, with `count(*)`. Or you can count how many values are filled in a column, i.e. not null, with `count(columnname)`.

Comment: Ok that is my bad, sorry. It is true I want to go through my column num_id, and see how many values there is in that column. Fx if 1, 5, 9, 4, 2, 9 would be total of 6 values

Comment: Select * from table; and just echo numrows simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just print total nos of row in a table as like:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM numbertable ");

$row = $result->fetch_row();

echo $row[0];
```

Comment: Thank you a lot devpro again ;)